# Check if string has other than spaces,underscore and character

Tags: php

i want to check if string has other than spaces,underscore,digit and character.

i have created the following code.But this is not working when i add any other special character or hyphen.

For example take this string.Now this is not valid.when i remove #%#% from string valid.

```
$string = 'a1uper___ w__#%#%';
if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z_]/',$string)){      
   echo 'valid';
 }
 else{
   echo 'not valid';
}
```

I have tried the following pattern also:

```
'/[a-zA-Z_]/'
'/^[a-zA-Z_]/'
'/[a-z][A-Z][_]/',...
```

please help

Comment: what is there in your input string can you show an example

Comment: do you mean that you want to match only character a-zA-z AND UNDERSCORE _ ????

Comment: yes and spaces also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
<?php

$string = 'a1uper___ w__ ';

if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z_\/\s\d]+$/i',$string)){      
    echo 'valid';
}
else{
    echo 'not valid';
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/806911

Note:-

```
a-zA-Z    is for characters
_         for underscores
/s        for spaces
d         for digits
```

Now `'/^[a-zA-Z_\/\s\d]+$/i'`  will check that string doesn't contain anything apart from the above mentioned.

If string have above mentioned things only then `valid` otherwise `invalid`.

That's why:-

`a1uper___ w__` is valid (only characters and underscores are there)

`a1uper___ w__#%#%` is invalid (because of having unmatched characters `#%#%` )

Reference:-

1. https://regex101.com/
2. http://www.phpliveregex.com/
3. https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html

Comment: yes this is working.Please explain how to create the pattern.I need to create more pattern like this?

Comment: @PhoetEst  you string can contain digits

Comment: ya digit can be there

Comment: @PhoetEst accept the answer please if solved your problem :)

Comment: thank you so much for your time.I accepted the answer.Is there any other source to create pattern?

Comment: Is that necessary to add this +$/i in pattern?

Comment: @PhoetEst  not necessary

Comment: @PhoetEst  you can't remove `+$`. you can remove `i` only :-https://eval.in/806949

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
$string = 'a1uper___ w__#%#%';
if(preg_match('/[\'"^!@#$%&*()£+}{~?><>,|=¬\\-]/',$string)){        
    echo 'not valid';
}
else{
    echo 'valid string';
}
```